# Convexity and monotonicity

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f(n)$ be non-negative real valued function defined for each natural number $n$.

If $f$ is convex and $lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ exists as a finite number, then can we conclude that $f$ is non-increasing?

Comment: "exists" $\: \mapsto \:$ "exists and is finite" $\;\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes, I just editted it

Answer (score 1):

This is true: Recall that $f$ is convex if and only if for every fixed $x$ the function $g(y)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ is non-decreasing. Now if $g(y_0)=c>0$ for some $y_0$ then for $y\geq \max\{ x,y_0\}$ we get that $f(x)-f(y)\leq c(x-y)$, or in other words, $f(y)\geq f(x) +c(y-x)$. Therefore, by letting $y\to \infty$, we see that $f$ can't have a finite limit. Therefore $g\leq 0$ and this is equivalent to $f$ being non-increasing.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is *not* non-increasing, there exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1 < x_2$ and $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.  The secant through $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ has positive slope, and by convexity, the graph of $f$ lies above that secant on $(x_2,\infty)$.  Therefore $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$.  Contraposing, if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists and is finite, then $f$ is non-increasing.